# Make a Menu (and underlying functions) available to all spreadsheet files I access

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing a bunch of GAS tools that I will use when designing and building spreadsheets. To make it easy to access these, I created a menu item that allows me to quickly access these tools. However, I want to have this menu available every time I use Google spreadsheets, not just on a specific spreadsheet that I have added the scripts to. I guess this would be analogous to an add-in in Excel The tools and functions are available to all spreadsheets opened in Excel, but aren't part of the spreadsheet.

Is this possible with Google spreadsheets/apps? All of my research on this has turned up answers where the code needs to be attached to a specific spreadsheet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use script in all spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221994/use-script-in-all-spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0):

No. You will have to add it to each of your spreadsheets. But you can add the same script to each of your spreadsheets by [using libraries](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_libraries) and using the [onInstall trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) to add the onOpen trigger to each spreadsheet.