# Is it possible to create a Apps Script for every spreadsheet I am using in my drive?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a script in one spreadsheet. How can I make it available for all of my Google Spreadsheets? I don't want to submit it to the gallery because it is for internal use.

Comment: See my answer on [this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351049). There isn't a way to automatically install scripts on spreadsheets.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use script in all spreadsheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25221994/use-script-in-all-spreadsheets)

Answer (score 0):

Make a library. Manually include it on each ss.